# Get window_ID of gnome-terminal window by tab name (may not be active tab)

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm running gnome-terminal in SLES-11.  I work on several debug and support issues running in parallel (EDA related) and have as many 15 desktops with a gnome terminal window in each one (one gnome-terminal process with multiple windows across all desktops).

The gnome terminal window in each desktop has several named tabs, eg Ticket_number, VIEW, LIB, RUN debug, etc.

Here's what I'm trying to find:

Given a name string, find the window_ID of the gnome terminal window containing that a tab with that name.  The named tab may not be the active tab (will not be in WM_NAME)

What I've tried so far:

- searching environment of gnome-terminal process:  no tab name info at all
- Searching window xprops:  only shows info for current active tab

I don't have root access and don't have any choice to change OS, gnome version or terminal app.

Are there any other ideas I could pursue?
Given a name string, find the X window ID of the gnome-terminal window(s) containing that named tab, even if the named tab is not the active tab.

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: Maybe my answer to my own similar question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67956491/7369280

Answer (score 0):

You can use "xdotool search" to get the windowID. Insert between quotes the terminal title:

```
xdotool search --name "text_to_search"
```

To install "xdotool" type:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: Thank you for offering to help.

You wrote:
> xdotool search --name "text_to_search"

The man page for xdotool says:  
" Match against the window name. This is the same string that is displayed in the window titlebar."  
  
I write in my question:  
>  The named tab may not be the active tab (will not be in WM_NAME)  
  
You wrote:  
> sudo apt-get install xdotool  
  
I wrote in my original question:  
> I don't have root access  
  
So, thank you for trying to help, but this is not a usable solution for the two reasons given in my original question.  
  
Best Regards,

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I don't know any other way to help you. Good luck! Best Regards,