# Automatic meaningful titles for GNOME Terminal tabs

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

(related: [Identify gnome-terminal window by tab title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030612/identify-gnome-terminal-window-by-tab-title))

When I open several tabs in GNOME Terminal (Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42) on my Ubuntu 22.04, [all tabs have the uninformative title "Terminal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U99Ur.png). I want them to be *automatically* titled:

1. the current working directory if it's in shell prompt (e.g. `/home/user123/Downloads`)
2. the name of the open process (e.g. `vim ~/.bashrc`) in case there is an open process.

How can I achieve that? I use `bash`, but I can switch to `zsh` if necessary.

[image: bunch of tabs, all titled "Terminal"]

Answer (score 1):

From another thread somewhere on the internet:

```
function termtitle()
{
    printf "\033]0;$*\007";
}
```

I put this in my .bashrc right above my PS1Update(). Then I call it in PS1Update, right after I update the prompt. I call it with a string constructed from some env flags, username, hostname, pwd. You can put almost anything. I throw in $0. I did try using $PS1, but I use color and I think the printf in termtitle() trips over the escape sequences. So I build another string with the same info but w/o color.

Every time the prompt is updated, so it the terminal window/tab title, like if I change dir, ssh to another machine.

Hope this helps!